# Angular-Highcharts: Cannot read property of 'Apartment' of undefined of an object

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with Angular and I have two objects.

Object one have mock data and object two have data pull from the cloud via xmlHttpRequest. When I use object one in Highcharts I get the intended result but with object two I get

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Condo' of undefined
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Apartment' of undefined

According to the console.log, two objects look and should be identical.

Object One:

```
var secondChartData = {
   Condo: [120],
   Apartment: [302],
}
//console log: secondChartData {Condo: Array(1), Apartment: Array(1)}
```

Object Two:

```
buildingTypeObj = {};
buildingType: any[] = [];
buildingSize: any[] = [];
constructor() {
  // other codes
  this.buildingType.push(...from Firebase...);
  this.buildingSize.push(...from Firebase...);
  for(var j = 0; j < this.buildingType.length; j++) {
    this.buildingTypeObj[this.buildingType[j]] = [this.buildingSize[j]];
  }
  //console log: secondChartData {Condo: Array(1), Apartment: Array(1)}
}
```

Highcharts:

```
ngAfterViewInit): void {
  // other codes
  function renderSecond(e) {
    var point = this;
    series: [{
      data: this.buildingTypeObj[point.name], // doesn't work
      //data: secondChartData[point.name], // works
    }]
  }
}
```

REST API via async because that was the system was setup:

```
static async getInfo() {
  // other codes
  const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpREquest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", groupsEndpoint, false); // false for async
  // other codes
}
```

I do not understand why object two returns an error.

Can the error be caused by async?

[Here is my Fiddle to show the intended behaviors](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/1189/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used an **ES5** function syntax, the context of **this** is changed.

You can no longer access **buildingTypeObj** inside your component with **this**.

Instead, have above your function a reference of **this**.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // other codes
  const self = this;
  function renderSecond(e) {
    series: [{
      data: self.buildingTypeObj[this.name],
      data: secondChartData[this.name], 
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good to learn something new.  Your answer solved my question that I been stuck on for three days.  You're a savior.  Thank you so much.